# What is the name for a very old oven that heats up a house using burning gas?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Like this one:
[image: super-oven]

The gas goes through the tubes and you light some paper on fire in the oven.
It will slowly heat up a brick that later releases the heat.

Comment: From your description, the generic term would be *brick [storage heater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_heater)*, although modern devices are powered by electricity. The device in you picture looks as tough it was made in the 19th century.

Comment: Do you have the original source for this photograph? Website, perhaps? The actual location and approximate date when the photo was taken would be even better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like a [**masonry heater**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masonry_heater).

According to Wikipedia, a **masonry heater** (or **masonry stove**, **ceramic stove**, **tile stove**) is a device for warming an interior space through radiant heating, by capturing the heat from periodic burning of fuel (usually wood), and then radiating the heat at a fairly constant temperature for a long period....In some areas of central and eastern Europe, these heaters are sometimes effectively fired using grass, straw, and hay. It is also common in eastern Europe to modify these efficient heaters so that they are connected to the **gas** network and are **fueled with gas**.

Comment: Yeah, and there probably are a half-dozen other terms for the things.  It's the type of device which would develop localized names.